# How can I map two different cursor from stored procedure with config xml only using Mybatis

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-mapper

`Author` (Cursor 1 Data)

| ID | NAME | PUBLISH_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 123 |
| 2 | Jane | 345 |

`Book` (Cursor 2 Data)

| PUBLISH_ID | BOOK_ID | BOOK_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | B101 | C# |
| 123 | B102 | Python |
| 345 | J001 | SQL |
| 345 | J002 | JAVA |

```
Class Author {
  String Id
  String authName;
  List<Books> books
}

Class Books {
   int publishId;
   int bookId;
   String bookName;
}
```

**Question**: how can it be mapped so that author can have only their books and want to display each author with  their own books only?

**I tried**: there are two separate cursors `Author` and `Books`. I will have to use mybatis xmlconfig mapper. I can't use a query to achieve only mybatis mapper config xml

Map I tried shown here doesn't work:

```
<resultMap id="authorMap type="demo.Author">
  <id property="Id" column="Id"></id>
  <collection property="Books" column="publishId" type="ArrayList" resultMap="booksMap" />
</resultMap>
<resultMap id="booksMap" type="demo.Books">
  <result property="publishId" column="publish_id"/>
  <result property="bookId" column="book_id"/> 
</resultMap>
```

I'm expecting to map base on publish id so each author only their multiple books.

```
   Id:1
   authNm: John
   Email: John@g.com
   book:
     publishId: 123,
     bookId: B101

     publishId: 123,
     bookId: B102

   Id:2
   authNm:Jane
   book:
    publishId: 345,
    bookId: J001

    publishId: 345,
    bookId: J002`
```

Comment: MyBatis supports this ([see](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-59543132) how it works with MS SQL Server), however, there seems to be a bug in the Oracle driver and I couldn't make it work (tested with version 23.2.0.0). In case someone can report the issue to Oracle, [here](https://gist.github.com/harawata/66ccb4189d0e21a5eb9e383c52695523)  is the plain JDBC code that reproduces the issue (see the comment for the details).

Comment: For some reason, I assumed that you are using Oracle. If that is not the case, please add the information about the DB/driver to the question.

Comment: @ave Thanks for your response and yes you're correct i am using Oracle 21.3.0.0 for ojdbc8

Comment: Then, my first comment still stands. It will work once the driver issue is resolved (please report it if you can). FYI, you can get the cursors as independent `List`s via `OUT` parameters like [this](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/bca364d6a42571b34d9508992113e7ca145b1001/so-56834806/src/test/resources/test/Mapper.xml#L21), however, you may have to 'join' these lists by yourself.